# Haskell - how do you make a loop that has getLine within it?

Tags: haskell, function-call

I want to create a loop which will take user input i.e. getLine, during each iteration of the loop. Is this possible within the main or by using the getLine function within a parameter pass or not at all? I'm relatively new to Haskell and I've gotten my head around most of it but this I'm not certain about. Obviously pattern matching will be used to exit it, but how could I get the user input. I've attempted to figure this out myself but each time failing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the IO monad for your funtions, for making a loop you can just make a **recursive call**, check this example:

```
-- This just wraps the getLine funtion but you could operate over the input before return the final result
processInput :: IO String
processInput = do
    line <- getLine
    return $ map toUpper line


-- This is our main loop, it handles when to exit
loop :: IO ()
loop = do
    line <- processInput
    putStrLn line
    case line of
        "quit"    -> return ()
        otherwise -> loop

-- main is the program entry point
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome to the haskel input example"
    loop
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/ViolentMotherlyFonts)

Comment: @RobinZigmond, I mentioned it in the comment, I just wanted to point that if he need to transform the input string it can be done there. Just to show the OP an example with 3 main points. 1, a funtion that does some operation, 2, the main loop and 3, the entry point.

Comment: Sorry @NetWave, I noticed that after posting, so deleted my current. But I still think it's confusing to a beginner - you say it "wraps" `getLine`, without defining what you mean by "wraps", when it's in fact exactly the same.